# Committed use discounts: How to apply to a VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-cloud-billing

I purchased a VM with a committed use discount from GCP and it's active but now I would think that this VM would be added to my VM instances list but it's not.
My two old VM's are still running but I don't see my VM that should be connected to my committed use discount purchase.

Does anybody know how to proceed to setup a VM with my purchase?

Thanks,
Claudio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Committed use discounts are automatically applied to the project they were purchased under, and are only applied to the number of cores that were specified when the commitment was purchased.

So for example, if the commitment was made for 4 cores for 24 hours and 8 were used, the discount will be applied to the 4 cores.

It is also specific to a region. If you purchase a committed usage discount for us-east1 it won't apply to a VM in us-central1 for instance.

You can find more detailed information and some examples on this article [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts) .